# Extract Image source from nested div and a tag in JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

```
 <div class='ym-gbox adds-header'> 
     <a href='javascript:(void);' >
         <a href="http://epaper.thedailystar.net/" target="_blank">
         <img src="http://epaper.thedailystar.net/images/edailystar.png" alt="edailystar" style="float: left; width: 100px; margin-top: 15px;">
         </a>
         <a href="http://www.banglalink.com.bd/celebrating10years" target="_blank" style="display:block;float: right;">
         <img width="490" height="60" src="http://bd.thedailystar.net/upload/ads/2015/02/12/BD-News_490x60.gif" alt="banglalink" >
         </a>
     </a>
</div>
```

This is the html portion. From here I want to extract the image source of image tag with source address **src="http://epaper.thedailystar.net/images/edailystar.png"** using jsoup in android. But I failed. If anyone give the answer I will be thankful to him.

Here is my code

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements img = document.select("div[class=ym-gbox adds-header]").first().select("a[href=http://epaper.thedailystar.net/] > img[src]");
String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
```

Comment: What's the url? so i can try..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention `url`, i assume `url` is http://epaper.thedailystar.net/index.php

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://epaper.thedailystar.net/index.php").timeout(10*1000).get();
Elements div = doc.select("div.logo");
Elements get = div.select("img");
System.out.println(get.attr("abs:src"));
```

Output :

```
http://epaper.thedailystar.net/images/edailystar.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through elements to choose the element that suits your needs. Like so:

```
Elements elements = document.getElementsByTag("img");

for (Element element : elements) {
    if (element.attr("src").endsWith("png")) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("src"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply to Yuva Raj and Xryaznov.

Comment: To Yuva Raj, Your code works for the ** url:  http://epaper.thedailystar.net/index.php ** . But when i use the ** url: http://www.thedailystar.net/ ** it does not work means it can not fetch the image. Can you tell me why this is happening. I have tried all the ways but failed

Comment: @user3256010 if `url` varies, `div` too will vary.